# calculate date from seconds in php

Tags: php, date, time, seconds

Calculating future date from seconds.

```
$var = 5183990; //seconds
$today = '2013-02-16 11:00:00'; //date
```

like I have `5183990` seconds as a variable $var.
Now I want to know future date/time after `5183990` seconds from current time.

Comment: `date('r', time() + $seconds)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `time()` returns the current timestamp in seconds, just add your interval in seconds to it, then format it as a date:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()+$var);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
strtotime('2013-02-16 11:00:00')-time()+$var;
```

details : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
echo date("Y m d h:i:s a",time()+$var);
```

where,

`time()` returns the current time then add the seconds in `$var` it will produce the time after `$var seconds`....the `date()` then formats that to your choice...